# App crashes on start up regularly.. service not registered?

Tags: android, service, andengine

For some reason, my app crashes on start up very regularly; usually after a few successful launches. It's the same exception every single time, but Google hasn't helped. I have no idea what any of this stuff is even doing. I am not using services. I am making a game in AndEngine. I am using AdMob, IAB, analytics and services, but I don't think this is what is causing the issue? My game hasn't always been doing this.

```
12-20 03:44:19.230: E/ActivityThread(11653): Activity com.grossman.plow.GameActivity has      leaked ServiceConnection ano@40e69400 that was originally bound here
12-20 03:44:19.230: E/ActivityThread(11653): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.grossman.plow.GameActivity has leaked ServiceConnection ano@40e69400 that was originally  bound here
12-20 03:44:19.230: E/ActivityThread(11653):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:887)
12-20 03:44:19.230: E/ActivityThread(11653):    at  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
12-20 03:44:19.250: E/AndroidRuntime(11653): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: ano@40e69400
12-20 03:44:19.250: E/AndroidRuntime(11653):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:945)
12-20 03:44:19.250: E/AndroidRuntime(11653):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened to me on every of my live wallpaper app..after successful few launches it give out an error, But after that i can again open the live wallpaper successfully.Hope you are facing same problem. And i recently solved it by adding some conditions to check whether our sprites are null or not. 
May be u are using some sprite movements or changes on just after your game starts.may be in the splash screen.so sometimes the sprites are not loaded and that will gives out the same error. So just put an

```
    if(sprite !=null){//do action 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code from GameActivity, but it sounds like a problem if you were using bindService on its own and it would crash during different application states.

Comment: thats the thing. i am not even sure what code i should be providing. the error in my log just points me into java.. apparently some people were suffering from similar results from v3 of in app billing (which i am also using), but even with the suggested fix, it happens. in any of my own code, i am definitely not using any services.

Comment: by own code, i mean any stuff i've written :D there is definitely service stuff happening in in app billing